# Como funciona e por que usar o padrão de projeto Command?

Tags: design-pattern, engenharia-de-software

Eu venho estudando os padrões de projetos e acabei me deparando com o padrão de projeto Command. Eu ainda não entendi bem como ele funciona, me corrijam caso esteja errado, mas pelo que vi por que eu deveria encapsular uma ação em forma de objeto? Não seria mais fácil simplesmente chamar diretamente essa ação? E quando eu devo usar esse padrão?

Eu não sei se entendi 100%, mas pelo que vi é possível tornar as coisas mais "palpáveis" com o Command uma vez que ele transforma uma ação em um objeto. Não me encontro usando ele de outra forma, mesmo assim deixo essa edição caso alguém precise um dia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E se você não sabe exatamente o que é esta ação, como você resolve isto? Você sabe que uma ação precisa ser executada, mas o objeto é que deve determinar qual será ela, precisa de algum mecanismo para resolver isto.

Antes de falar sobre este padrão de projeto específico quero dizer que o [Peter Novig já dizia que *design patterns* só existem por deficiência da linguagem](https://norvig.com/design-patterns/), se a linguagem fosse poderosa o suficiente não precisaria usar nenhum. Claro que todos os padrões não podem ser colocados nas linguagens, mas os principais poderiam em tese ser colocados, ainda que violaria a filosofia da linguagem.

Por outro lado padrão de projeto estão em toda parte, então mesmo que a linguagem tenha uma capacidade que evite a necessidade de você criar um código que siga os preceitos de um padrão de projeto ainda existirá esse padrão, só que ele já está na linguagem.

Dito isto, existem linguagens que não precisam criar exatamente este padrão para obter o mesmo efeito.

As linguagens que precisam normalmente precisam de um contrato que indique qual é o método que será usado para executar uma ação qualquer, então todos componentes da aplicação que precisarem executar algo em específico sabe que pode mandar executar esse comando genérico qualquer chamando este método. Isto poderá ser feito em todos os tipos que tenha implementado este método, sendo que em algumas linguagens isto se dá através de uma herança de classe ou de interface.

Na implementação deste método no objeto que terá o comando que você pode colocar o código que quiser que dê a ação pretendida. Em geral é chamar algum outro método que tem uma ação determinada.

Esta é uma forma de os componentes que chama a execução não precisarem saber o que será executado, sabe apenas que algo será executado, e o componente que tem ação não precisa saber detalhes de como será chamado aquilo.

Um exemplo comum é ter algo assim ([retirado da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)):

```cs
using static System.Console;

namespace CommandPattern {    
    public interface ICommand {
        void Execute();
    }
    /* The Invoker class */
    public class Switch {
        ICommand closedCommand;
        ICommand openedCommand;
        public Switch(ICommand closedCommand, ICommand openedCommand) {
            this.closedCommand = closedCommand;
            this.openedCommand = openedCommand;
        }
        // Close the circuit / power on
        public void Close() => this.closedCommand.Execute();
        // Open the circuit / power off
        public void Open() => this.openedCommand.Execute();
    }
    /* An interface that defines actions that the receiver can perform */
    public interface ISwitchable {
        void PowerOn();
        void PowerOff();
    }
    /* The Receiver class */
    public class Light : ISwitchable {
        public void PowerOn() => WriteLine("The light is on");
        public void PowerOff() => WriteLine("The light is off");
    }
    /* The Command for turning off the device - ConcreteCommand #1 */
    public class CloseSwitchCommand : ICommand {
        private ISwitchable switchable;
        public CloseSwitchCommand(ISwitchable switchable) this.switchable = switchable;
        public void Execute() => switchable.PowerOff();
    }
    /* The Command for turning on the device - ConcreteCommand #2 */
    public class OpenSwitchCommand : ICommand {
        private ISwitchable switchable;
        public OpenSwitchCommand(ISwitchable switchable) this.switchable = switchable;
        public void Execute() => switchable.PowerOn();
    }
    /* The test class or client */
    internal class Program {
        public static void Main() {
            string argument = arguments.Length > 0 ? arguments[0].ToUpper() : null;
            ISwitchable lamp = new Light();
            // Pass reference to the lamp instance to each command
            ICommand switchClose = new CloseSwitchCommand(lamp);
            ICommand switchOpen = new OpenSwitchCommand(lamp);
            // Pass reference to instances of the Command objects to the switch
            var @switch = new Switch(switchClose, switchOpen);
            // Switch (the Invoker) will invoke Execute() on the command object.
            if (argument == "ON") @switch.Open();
            else if (argument == "OFF") @switch.Close();
            else WriteLine("Argument \"ON\" or \"OFF\" is required.");
        }
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/CommandPattern.cs).

Assim eu posso executar algo só sabendo que o objeto tem essa capacidade de executar um comando, não preciso saber nenhum detalhe do objeto, ele pode fazer o que quiser, ser qualquer coisa, só precisa ter a capacidade de comando através da implementação da interface.

Comment: Tem apenas uma coisa que eu não entendi, como eu não saberia qual ação executar? e por favor poderia me falar quando utilizar?

Comment: Bom, me parece que está caindo naquela situação que a gente sempre fala, está pegando uma solução e procurando um problema pra aplicar. Isso não costuma dar certo. O exemplo não ajuda entender quando usar? Não demonstra como não sabe o que executar? É uma questão de padronizar nomenclaturas de chamada, você cria uma indireção porque naquele momento do código ainda não está determinada ação específica ser executada. Se acha complicado, não use, faça do jeito simples, sempre é melhor. Só crie complicações no código se você ver necessidade, quando não está conseguindo ver é que não precisa disto.

Comment: Um lugar que se usa é nas ações do menu de uma aplicação por exemplo um editor de texto (um Word da vida), se você quiser oferecer a opção de _Undo_ ("desfazer"), você codifica no objeto os passos para executar a ação e os passos para desfazer essa mesma ação.